# Adjusted R squared on a holdout set

Tags: regression, model-selection, regression-coefficients, r-squared, out-of-sample

The formula for adjusted $R^2$ is: 
$$
1 - \frac{(n-1)}{(n-p-1)}(1-R^2)
$$

where $r^2$ is the coefficient of determination, $n$ is the number of points, and $p$ is the number of parameters the model has.

If I want the adjusted $R^2$ from a holdout set, is $n$ the number of points in the data the model was trained on, or the number of points in the holdout set?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to make the adjustment on a hold-out sample, or if you did, $p$ would equal 1.  For evaluation in a hold-out sample, all coefficients estimated in the training sample must be frozen.  But you really should not be using that formula for $R^2$ as it implies you are forcing $R^2$ to be positive.  The correct formula allows $R^{2} < 0$ because predictions can be worse than chance.  So compute $R^{2} = 1 - \frac{SSE}{SST}$ where $SSE$ is sum of squared errors and $SST$ is sum of squares total ($(n-1) \times$ the variance of $Y$).

Comment: Frank, thanks for your response. I don't understand why $p$ would be 1. The same model is being applied to a holdout set, so the same weights and their values are being used.

Also, this isn't the formula for R^2, but rather, for adjusted R^2.

Comment: Yes I know it's the formula for $R^{2}_{adj}$.  $p=1$ since the coefficients are frozen, i.e., all predictors are reduced down to a single linear predictor for application to the independent sample.  But you need to use the primitive formula for $R^2$ above anyway.

Comment: This is indeed a delicate matter. Some authors propose using the train variance in the denominator, but I agree with @FrankHarrell, that $R^2$ should indeed be allowed to be smaller than 0. Which is to say: predictions have MORE variability than raw data.